# Yahoo! Messenger API limit expire time

Tags: php, yahoo-api

I'm using Yahoo! Messenger API, it has 5000 query limit per day.

So I should add a function to my app for switching to another server if my server reached the limit. And, if the limit has expired, switch to default server.

THE MAIN QUESTION: When the limit has expired? What time at which timezone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can by-pass the limit simply counting requests and using another server(s) for a temporary time but methods like this against [Terms of Use](http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/messengerimapi/tou.html), more importantly; this methodology is not a real solution especially growing apps which depends on a 3rd party non-free/limited API.

From Yahoo! Messenger [IM SDK using guidelines](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch06s02.html) :

> Applications can freely use the Yahoo! Messenger IM SDK for up to
>   5,000 daily unique users. If an application exceeds 5,000 daily users,
>   you (the developer) will be notified through email and may be asked to
>   enter into a commercial agreement with Yahoo!. A commercial agreement
>   may require the developer to:
>
> - Furnish platform and OS data. You may be
>     asked to provide Yahoo! information on the platforms, operating
>     systems, or in the case of mobile applications, the mobile devices
>     their service is running on. The developer may also be asked to
>     provide the number of users on each platform, operating system and
>     device.
> - Include additional feature requirement in the product. You may
>     be asked to include other Yahoo! related feature requirements in their
>     application. Such feature requirements would be based on services that
>     Yahoo! provides.
> - Enter into a profit sharing arrangement. If the
>     application is a commercial application, the commercial agreement may
>     require a profit sharing arrangement between you and Yahoo!

Comment: where does the ToU say about my solution? i've 2-3 servers for my app. if any problem occurred, i just get help from other mini-app (on other servers)